# mod_rewrite, change one URL with query to a completely different URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am migrating data from one content management system to another.  There is no relationship between old URLs and new URLs, although both contain query strings.  I am trying to set up a set a rewrites that will redirect broad category lists of data from one to the other.

Here's a sample:

OLD
rss.php?categoryID=53

NEW
index.php?module=news&type=user&func=list&tid=1&filter=blogtopic:eq:19

I tried

RewriteRule ^rss.php\?categoryID=53 index.php?module=news&type=user&func=list&tid=1&filter=blogtopic:eq:19 [L]

but it doesn't match. If I follow that one with

RewriteRule ^rss.php index.php?module=news&type=user&func=list&tid=1 [L]

if DOES match, so I conclude that the question mark in the old URL is causing the problem. I am already escaping the question mark. What do I do?

I will probably end up with about 50 of these in my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string (all that stuff after the **?**) in a `RewriteRule`, you need to use a `RewriteCond` and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING} var:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^categoryID=53$
RewriteRule ^rss\.php$ /index.php?module=news&type=user&func=list&tid=1&filter=blogtopic:eq:19 [L]
```

Or change the brackets to `[R=301,L]` if you want to redirect the browser.

Comment: Thanks.  Your "or" confuses me.  I don't have to do the RewriteCond if I redirect instead?

Comment: You still need the RewriteCond, just add a `R=301` in the brackets at the end of the `RewriteRule` if you wanted to actually redirect the browser instead of internally rewriting